# Fight club novel sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the novel, when narrator tells about his support group visits and the character Bob he met there. He says that Bob told him that he had a gym and appeared on t.v for chest expansion programme.Then he says and I quote:

> "Strangers with this kind of honesty makes me go a big rubbery one, if  you know what mean."

I honestly don't know what he means by that, "rubbery one". TIA

Comment: He's talking about a semi-erection. In other words, he responds positively to such strangers, up to a point.

Answer (score 3):

He's talking about a semi-erection. In other words, he responds positively to such strangers, up to a point.

Comment: Just read over the passage a few minutes ago, and yes, this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The expression in the movies is a mix of "this girl/boy/thing makes me go hard" (gives me an erection) and "rubbery one" which is just referring to non-firm material similar to rubber.

So "strangers ... makes me go a rubbery one" means "strangers ... give me a semi-erection".

---

The other answer is good enough, but I don't agree with the "responding positively" part. One can get a boner to strangers that one otherwise has no positive feelings about and getting a boner is not a positive sensation/manifestation in most social settings.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a semi-erection he's referencing: he's facetiously referencing the kind of erection that happens quickly and without physical stimulation. The perceived visual texture of such erection would look "shiny" and "rubbery" - with that line, Palahniuk is using exaggeration to get his point across.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the correct interpretation?